# Add email notification subscription option for new Blog Posts in Sitefinity

Tags: blogs, sitefinity, email-notifications

Sitefinity (version 6.3.5) has a feature to allow users to subscribe to comments to be notified when there are new comments added via email.  Is there anyway to do the same thing for blog posts themselves?

I am thinking similar to the functionality in WordPress to sign up to be notified when a new blog post is added to a blog.  I've seen the RSS feed but looking for a way to allow the users to be notified via email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is possible, but not without some custom coding.

http://bit.ly/sf-customLogicForSFWidgets

> 1. Create a .class file in your Sitefinity project solution then we must find out how to inherit one widget. For this example I will be inheriting Sitefinity login control.
> 2. To find the needed  path that should be inherited (`Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.LoginControl`) go to `Administration->Settings->Advanced->Toolboxes->PageControls->Sections->Login->Tools->Login` and find `textbox: Control CLR Type or Virtual Path`. In it you can take the path `Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.LoginControl` as well as other properties that will not be needed from this example.
> 3. In the .class file created in step 1 inherit from Login Control.
> 4. Save the file and build Sitefinity project (if the project is website project build will not be needed).
> 5. Now register new widget that will be the modified login control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SitefinityWebApp.Custom
{
    public class Class1 : Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.LoginControl
    {
        protected override void LoginForm_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do Custom Stuff Here Before Base Call

            // call base login class when done
            base.LoginForm_Authenticate(sender, e);

            // Do Custom Stuff Here After Base Call
        }
    }
}
```